# How do I make guard gem fail non-fatally from a syntax error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets, guard

Rails 3.1, guard 0.8.8, Fedora 13

I have guard configured to watch changes to the jquery templates and recompile javascript assets using sprockets.  Whenever I work on the templates and generate a syntax error, guard tries to run sprokets which fails with a SyntaxError exception.

This causes guard to fail fatally, and it no longer reacts to file changes...  unless I restart guard or interactively tell it to reload.

Is this a normal, expected behavior?  Is there a way to make it fail non-fatally?